# How can I express returning either a vector or a reference to an allocated vector?

Tags: c++

I have a function that should return either a new vector or a reference to an existing one. I need this because in some situations the vector is already created and owned by somebody else and I want to avoid copying it.

*One option is to return `std::variant<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>&>`, but then the caller needs to add logic to discern what was returned.* (NOT ALLOWED)

Another option is to use a wrapper class (I avoid templates for clarity):

```
class VectorContainer {     

  VectorContainer() : v(std::vector<int>()), v_ptr(nullptr) {}
  VectorContainer(std::vector<int>& ref): v_ptr(&ref) {}

  std::vector<int>& get() {
    if (v_ptr == nullptr) return v;
    return *v_ptr;
  }

 private:
  std::vector<int> v;
  std::vector<int>* v_ptr;
};

VectorContainer f();
```

The reference is guaranteed to outlive VectorContainer and additionally, the code that owns the vector is fixed and you cannot change it. I believe this disallows using something like a shared pointer.

Is there an existing class in the standard library? If not, how can I do this?

Comment: Generally, one almost *never* need pointers to standard containers, smart or plain non-owning pointers doesn't matter. What is the reason you want pointers to your vector? What problem is that supposed to solve?

Comment: This seems to be a matter of **ownership** (in Rust this would be the question who has to delete the object). Maybe you should look first at the call sites. It might be something like _caching_. I mean a more higher level API. Somehow this looks too boiler-plateish. That is just my bla-bla.

Comment: I added some additional explanation regarding the first comment.

Comment: @XavierSpagnoloArrizabalaga Why `VectorContainer` may end up with a reference to a vector it doesn't own? Without `std::variant` how do you ensure that only one of the fields is populated at a time? It might be an XY problem, and I will appreciate if you give a little more context to why this design in the first place

Comment: "[You are] using a pointer because the field is not always populated" sound like you want either [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) or possibly [`std::expected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/expected) from the upcoming C++23 standard.

Comment: *"but then the caller needs to add logic to discern what was returned."* You do realize that this is exactly what you stated you ***wanted*** to happen when describing desired behaviour of the function?

Comment: With more information about where the vectors usually are stored and how long they live, probably a better solution can be created. But just from your information, you could return a `shared_ptr<vector>`. (In most cases using `shared_ptr` is a sign that object ownership has to be improved instead. So I seldom recommend it.) The vectors you would have returned the reference to would have to be also stored as `shared_ptr` from the beginning.

Comment: Now you added the information against shared pointer. Can you be more specific about the reasons for not owning (not even shared ownership)? Do you want to be able to delete the vector beforehand after all? How about `shared_ptr` with `weak_ptr`? Please give more information about the storage and lifetime of the vectors. And about the classes and functions calling each other.

Comment: Do you have a guarantee that the referenced vector is not deleted by its owner as long as you use it? And this owner should not also store the new copied vector (e.g. in a vector of vector)? Either because the owner is way up in the hierarchy, or the new copied vector is possibly so large that it should be directly freed after being used by the caller of the function? And the current owner won't change the storage of its vectors to `shared_ptr`, because the code is fixed? Then the solution with the wrapper perhaps really is the best way.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. Yes, the vector is not deleted as long as you use it. And also yes, the current owner's code cannot be changed and it is just a plain vector<int>. I was wondering if a class in the standard can be used which does exactly what this wrapper does. It looks like a common scenario.

Comment: Note that you cannot use a reference type as a template argument of `std::variant` (non-object types are not allowed).

Comment: @DanielLangr perhaps as `std::reference_wrapper`

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is close, but I would suggest having the reference always refer to the proper object:

```
class VectorContainer {
  private:
    std::vector<int> v_own;
  public:
    std::vector<int>& data;

    VectorContainer(std::vector<int> own) : v_own{std::move(own)}, data{v_own} {}
    VectorContainer(std::vector<int>& ref) : v_own{}, data{ref} {}

    ~VectorContainer() = default;
    VectorContainer& operator=(VectorContainer const&) = delete;
    VectorContainer& operator=(VectorContainer&&) = delete;
    VectorContainer(VectorContainer const& from) : 
      v_own{from.v_own},
      data{(&from.v_own == &from.data)?v_own:from.data} {
    }
    VectorContainer(VectorContainer&& from) :
      v_own{std::move(from.v_own)},
      data{(&from.v_own == &from.data)?v_own:from.data} {
    }
};
```

Here you always access `data` or you could hide `data` and add a wrapper like this:

```
std::vector<int>& operator*() const {
  return data;
}
// or a conversion operator to std::vector<int>&
```

Either way, whether or not there is indirection is hidden from the user. You always see a reference. Note that lugging around an empty vector has virtually no overhead. The initialisation is minimal.

Example:

```
struct Example {
  std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};

  VectorContainer example(bool const b) {
    if (b)
      return VectorContainer(std::vector{0}); // new vector
    else
      return VectorContainer(v); // reference to v
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, and is there any class in the standard to do this? This looks like a common scenario.

Comment: @XavierSpagnoloArrizabalaga Not that I know of. I wouldn't say this is a common scenario. As you say, the closest would be `std::variant`. Which you could use with `std::visit([](std::vector<int>& ref) { /*...*/ }, variant_result);` without having to put much burden on the user.

Comment: `VectorContainer` should be uncopyable and unmoveabe, if you have a reference member, as you can't repoint it.

Comment: @Caleth Yes. At least one should take care how to formulate a copy or move operator. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Caleth There, I think this definition of move and copy constructor is the most sensible. If one were to keep the reference as pointer, one could also implement assignment operators.